# Netsuite - Add package dimensions to Mark Orders Packed Screen

Tags: netsuite, fulfillment

We are trying to use the bulk fulfillment screens within Netsuite to fulfill our orders, but there isn't an option for adding in package dimensions. (Which is important for UPS/Fedex dimensional weight calculations.)

Does anyone know how to input this field into the 'Mark Orders Packed' Bulk fulfillment screen? Or does anyone have any other solutions? (We can add package dimensions to individual IF, just not on the bulk screen.) I would like to add that field where the highlighted area is on the image.

[image]